# Call this.props in function outside render gives undefine

Tags: react-native, jsx

Im having this problem with my flatlist. Basically im destructing my code to make it more readable. However my problem whenever I call the this.props outside the render it gives my undefine. Here's my code below:

```jsx
renderItem(item) {
  console.log(this.props) // Gives me undefine
  return (
    <ListItem button>
      <Text>{item.item.name }</Text>
    </ListItem>
  )
}
render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
      data={countries.payload.data}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.name}
    />
  )
}
```

But if I did not separate to other function the renderItem. I can access the this.props:

```jsx
render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
      data={countries.payload.data}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => (
        <ListItem button onPress={() => this.props.onPressAction()}> // I get the correct value
          <Text>{item.name }</Text>
        </ListItem>
      )}
      keyExtractor={item => item.name}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: `renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this}`

Comment: Little typo there (missing closing parenthesis), should read `renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 4):

When using react-native and [ES6 classes](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#es6-classes) it won't automatically bind your functions that is declared on your classes, so `this` will be a live object represent for the unknown context or even `undefined` which caused `this.props` to be `undefined`.

We need to handle the correct value of `this` to our methods on our own. Therefore either use:

- Change to `this.renderItem.bind(this)`
- Or use arrow functions like `renderItem= () => {}`